# What is the Standard Company ID Card Size (With & Without Bleed & Trim )?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, template

Friends,

I'm going to design an ID Card for my Company..

I totally confused with the size of the ID Card Someone had mentioned its 3X2 Inches.

Can Anyone Explain me the correct size of the ID card or provide me a template in .psd or.ai

Comment: Contact your printer and ask them what their default sizes are. There are also a lot of online print shops, I'm sure you can find details sizes on one of those sites.

Comment: Can you refer me a website ??

Comment: https://www.moo.com/us/products/business-cards.html for example

Answer (score 4):

While size will vary by printer, country, and company, there actually *is* a standard size for identification cards: [ISO/IEC 7810](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_7810).

```
ID-1      85.60 × 53.98 mm     Most banking cards and ID cards
ID-2      105 × 74 mm          French and other ID cards; Visas
ID-3      125 × 88 mm          Passports
ID-000    25 × 15 mm           SIM cards
```

Personally, every company I have ever worked for used ID-1 size, which can fit into employee wallets and such.

Exact dimensions and bleeds are going to need to be worked out with your printer.

Answer (score 1):

"The most common card format is ID-1 or CR80. However, there are other standard card formats as well. The official format for the common ID card was codified by the International Organization for Standards (ISO) in the specification document ISO 7810 (Identification Cards-Physical Characteristics). According to this document the ID-1 (CR80) card has the following dimensions: 3.370 inches wide and 2.125 inches high. The thickness is 0.030 inches. This thickness is most commin, and it is called "30 mil".

However, ID-1 (CR80) card is too small in many cases for the name badges. That is why the larger card formats are usually used for the identification badges at the exhibitions, trade shows, and conferences. On the other hand, the smaller card formats are also used quite often as the identification tags."

[Standard and non-standard ID card formats](http://www.akond.net/index.php?issue_id=222)